# Maven maven-gpg-plugin fails on a "artifact has not been assembled yet"

Tags: java, maven

When trying to release ActiveJDBC, I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.1:sign (sign-artifacts) on project db-migrator-integration-test: The project artifact has not been assembled yet. Please do not invoke this goal before the lifecycle phase "package". -> [Help 1]
```

Full output can be found here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ipolevoy/26692894281151d7143a/raw/gistfile1.txt

Last release was done  in January, and I'm doing the same this time. 
Source code of the project is here: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have taken a look into your project and seen that you have configured to use maven-gpg-plugin versoin 1.5 but only on the root level. [You should use `pluginManagement` instead](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/pom.xml#L50). The log output shows your are using maven-gpg-plugin 1.1. Apart from that what have you changes in comparsion to january? Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: Here is the code that was released in January https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/releases/tag/activejdbc-root-1.4.10. You are correct: I need to use pluginManagement to ensure the right version of the plugin. I will do so and report back.

Comment: I think I made all the right changes in all poms, but still getting

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.1:sign (sign-artifacts) on project db-migrator-integration-test: The project artifact has not been assembled yet. Please do not invoke this goal before the lifecycle phase "package". -> [Help 1]


 As you can see, I specified version 1.5, but version 1.1 is still called.

Comment: Solved this problem! The real reason was that the module where GPG plugin was failing is an integration test, and it had no code. So, it had nothig to sign. I added a dummy class https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/db-migrator-integration-test/src/main/java/dummy/Dummy.java and set packaging to jar on this module. That made the GPG plugin happy!

Comment: Integration tests of plugin or your usual code ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, while teh build is succeeding, I still see that the version of plugin used is 1.1. Do you have an idea why? Looks like I have it configured correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem! The real reason was that the module where GPG plugin was failing is an integration test, and it had no code. So, it had nothig to sign. I added a dummy class:

https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/db-migrator-integration-test/src/main/java/dummy/Dummy.java

and set `packaging` to `jar` on this module. That made the GPG plugin happy!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. One module is an integration test module and I don't need to distribute it in a jar, so ideally I'd like to avoid packaging and signing it altogether. Has anyone encountered a solution for that, avoiding building a dummy jar?